# How do I animate a polar plot?

Tags: plotting, functions, animation

I have

```
r[θ_]:= Sin[θ/10]

ep[s_]:= PolarPlot[r[θ], {θ, 0, 2pi}, AxesLabel -> {"x","y"}]
Animate[ep[s], {s, 0, 2pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

But all it outputs is the full graph of Sin[θ/10]. Nothing is animated even though it's playing.

Replacing ep[s] with the full PolarPlot doesn't and shouldn't do anything.

Replacing ep[s] with Sin[θ/10] and range doesn't do anything either.

It could be that I'm missing something really obvious- it's like 2 AM right now.

Thanks

Comment: There is no `s` in `PolarPlot[r[θ], {θ, 0, 2pi}, AxesLabel -> {"x","y"}]`.

Comment: @Kuba is right, and in addition, you need to write $\pi$ as `Pi` (uppercase), when you don't want to define it yourself.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
r[θ_] := Sin[θ/10]
```

`ep` should only plot to its argument rather than `2Pi`  Use a fixed `PlotRange`

```
ep[s_] := 
 PolarPlot[r[θ], {θ, 0, s}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-.35, .6}, {-.5, .2}}]
```

`s` must start at a non-zero value

```
Animate[ep[s], {s, .01, 2 Pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```